# PowerShell How to Run Command Once For Every Entry in External File

Tags: powershell

I have a list of IPs that is stored in .txt file at C:\IPs.txt.
I'd like to create a PowerShell script that will execute a specific command for each entry in that file. Supposed IPs.txt have 2 entries:

```
10.0.0.0
100.0.0.0
```

What syntax would I need to use to execute?

```
Write-Host 10.0.0.0
Write-Host 100.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read the contents of the file. By default, it'll slurp one line at a time, at which point we can pipe the output to `ForEach-Object` and run the command:

```
Get-Content path\to\IPs.txt |ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

`$_` will refer to the current item in the pipeline